# QR code scanner back to the app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, qr-code, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap and JQM to create an application. I recently configure Barcode scanner on my app. It work perfectly.
But I have a problem. When I scan a QR code, I don't know how to come back to my app when the scan is done. 
I installed the zxing library barcode scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are integrating via `Intent`, then the application replies to you with the results once it is done scanning.

All of the details are wrapped up for you by the project in a few classes you can include:
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent